# How to resize an custom UIView from NIB inside of a UITableViewCell with Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, nib

*I want to load a custom view to a static `UITableViewCell` and resize the view to the horizontal bounds of the `UITableViewCell`.*

I achieved the loading, but I stuck with the resizing. Maybe some genius will help me :)

### For this problem, I created a sample project, which can be checked out here: [GitHub Repository of project](https://github.com/twofish187/StaticTableViewCell)

Here are the steps that I did:

**UITableView**:

1. Created a Single View App
2. In StoryBoard deleted the View and dragged a `TableViewController` (TVC) to the Storyboard. Embedded it in an `UINavigationController`.
3. Created a class "MasterTableViewController" (MTVC) as subclass of `UITableViewController`.
4. Connected TVC with the MTVC at the identity inspector.
5. Set the `UITableView` Content to "Static Cells" at the Attributes Inspector
6. The `UITableView` has two sections, each with a row. The first section and row can be ignored. The second section and row is the place where the uiview from nib will be loaded.
7. I created a Outlet from the `UITableViewCell` where the view will be loaded.

**UIView**:

8. I created a custom view as a nib `FirstDetailView.xib`(FDV) with the `InterfaceBuilder`.
9. Added some Labels and Textfields. Set suggested constraints.
10. Then I created a subclass from `UIView` `FirstDetailView.swift` connected it at the Identity Inspector with the FDV at the nib.
    At this point there only `IBOutlet` for the TextFields.

**Loading**:

11. The following code shows the MTVC with the code to load the view to the `UITableViewCell`:

import `UIKit`

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailCell: UITableViewCell!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // loading customized tableViewCell
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "FirstDetailView", bundle: nil)
    let nibs = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options:nil)
    let firstDetailView = nibs.first as? FirstDetailView
    if let firstView = firstDetailView {
        detailCell.contentView.addSubview(firstView)
    }
}
```

When I hit Play. The view will be loaded to the `UITableViewCell`. But the textfields go over the view bounds. What do I have to do, to fix the `UIView` bounds?
(The vertical size of the row is not the problem. Sorry but I cant post images due to few reputations. Please see the sample project at github)

**UPDATE or new Question**
If I write content in the textfields. How can I access them or get the content from the tableViews ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is loaded from a nib and added to the cell's contentView, you should add constraints to it to make it position properly inside the cell. Try again with the following code.

```
// do not translate autoresizingMask to constraints, create our own
firstView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
detailCell.contentView.addSubview(firstView)

// pin firstView edges to its superview
let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: detailCell.contentView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: detailCell.contentView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: detailCell.contentView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: detailCell.contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

detailCell.contentView.addConstraints([constraint1,constraint2,constraint3,constraint4])
```